# Sign in with django authentication from frontend

Tags: python, django

I have created a view which allows the user to sign in.

```
def signin(request):

    email = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
```

How should I verify that the user is signed in?

Is it when the user is accessing an API that requires user to be logged in first?

The documentation shows that we can use `request.user.is_authenticated` is `True` or not to verify.

However, I am not using django templates but `reactJS` to send POST requests.

How should I do it?

Should I include a `User` attribute in json body in the POST request?

Comment: `request.user.is_authenticated` works perfectly fine in Python code, it's not just for Django templates.

Comment: For example, I have an API which is called /order_food/ which requires user to login. The order_food POST request is sent with Axios. What kind of information should I provide in the POST request to let django know that its the user who send it?

Comment: if you are using an API you have to use JWT to do that if that is what you mean

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether you use django template or use reactjs to send Post request. So this function will be in the views.py file, you can add the @login_required decorator for all required endpoints, django have it own authentication(by default it will associate with the User model, but you can change it)to protect the API, and you can use DRF token or JWT in your application to post to serve(check this for details:http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)